# Is it possible to upload data directly to QGIS Cloud from a mobile phone?

Tags: qgis, mobile, qgis-cloud

I am going to be performing some field work, but I don't have a GPS unit as of yet due to cost.

Ideally I would like to pre-upload some features onto my QGIS cloud online map first, then go into the field and take elevation data from various points from my phone and have them uploaded on the spot to my online published map (as a point file).

Is there a way to do this directly without any other hardware?

Comment: Does QGIS Cloud is strong requirement or other software "cloud GIS + mobile" is suitable? What is OS in your mobile phone?

Comment: Dmitry, I have an iPhone so it would be using iOS. I haven't seen any information about additional software on the QGIS cloud plugin website.

Comment: Unfortunately I only know cloud GIS (not QGIS Cloud) + Android native mobile application solution.

Comment: There are many apps that will let you collect point data on your phone. The real question is whether you can upload that data to QGIS Cloud from your phone. I didn't see any mention of this possibility on their FAQ. If you haven't already done so, I recommend contacting the QGIS Cloud support team http://support.qgiscloud.com. If they don't have this feature already, they're probably working on it.

Comment: Thanks csk. After looking all morning on the subject, it certainly doesn't look like the 'direct upload' functionality is there. Alternatively, I would look for the option to collect the point data in gpx or dxf format then go back to the office to upload it into QGIS. I might have to do it that way